# prepopulating columns with creator's property fields like phone and Title in newform

Tags: custom-form, user-profile-property

ShaerPoint 2007. Any good client code to do this? Possible with a calculated column?

Answer (score 1):

I do it with jQuery and [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) or with a workflow after the fact.

In the workflow scenario, I create person/group columns that display the phone number or title, then set the fields to the created by field.

In the case of prepopulating, I use something like this:

```
<script src="../../js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../js/SPServices.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var User = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
        fieldName: "Name",
        debug: false
    });
    $("textarea[title='People Picker']").val(User);
    $("div[title='People Picker']").text(User);     
});
</script>
```

This example adds values to people picker fields, but could easily be a text box input.